# CSS: How to change background color

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

Here's the code: [LABOUM](http://view-source:http://laboumph.tumblr.com/)

Here's the Tumblr account: [LABOUM2](http://laboumph.tumblr.com)

I want to change the background color from #FFFFFF to #FFCFEA but I don't know which code to change. Please help! Thank you in advance. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this

```
body {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 110%;
}
```

To this

```
body {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFCFEA;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 110%;
}
```

On your template file. The line should be within two tags that are like `<style type="text/css"></style>`

Comment: The one inside the two tags <style stype="text/css"> says the following:

#s-m-t-tooltip {
    color:{color:text};
    background-color:{color:background};

Should I change {color:background} to #FFCFEA? :)

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. :) Just one more question. Please visit the blog and check it out. I want to change the inner background too another color too but I also haven't figured it out. Thanks a lot!! Really^^